# How would I detect insertion of the same key with a different value into a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So my goal for this problem is to, given 2 strings, `str1` and `str2`, create a dictionary such that the characters in `str1` are the keys and the corresponding characters in `str2` are the values.

ie. `crackthecode('apple','byytr')` returns 
    `{'a':'b','p':'y','l':'t','e':'r'}`
and if it is inconsistent, ie. `crackthecode('apple','byptr')` then returns
`{}`, an empty dictionary.

This is my code, I'm just not sure how to do the inconsistent case.

PS. I cannot use `zip` for this question.

Below is my code.

```py
def crackthecode(str1, str2):
  final = {}
  x = 0
  for i in list(str1):
    final[i]=str2[x]
    x = x + 1
  return final
```

All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what do u mean by 2 of the same keys? dict keys are unique and immutable!

Comment: @AmitKarnik. While the title is a bit misleading, the question itself explains quite well what OP means

Comment: @Sania. What would you do for `crackthecode('apple', 'xxxxx')`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist In that case you would return the empty dictionary `{}`

Comment: @Sania. Why? No key is inconsistent...

Comment: That's a good point. I guess each key would have the same value.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the key is already present in the dictionary, and compare the value with the new character. If they are not equal, return an empty dictionary. Otherwise, add the key-value pair to the dictionary.

You can use this code which uses the [EAFP principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python).

```
>>> def crackthecode(str1, str2):
    final = {}
    for i, key in enumerate(str1):
        try:
            if final[key] != str2[i]:
                return {}
        except KeyError:
            final[key] = str2[i]
    return final

>>> crackthecode('apple','byytr')
{'a': 'b', 'p': 'y', 'l': 't', 'e': 'r'}
>>> crackthecode('apple','byptr')
{}
```

---

**Edit:** Same code without using `enumerate` (requested by OP)

```
def crackthecode(str1, str2):
    final = {}
    for i in range(len(str1)):
        try:
            if final[str1[i]] != str2[i]:
                return {}
        except KeyError:
            final[str1[i]] = str2[i]
    return final
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using enumerate?

Comment: You can simply use `for i in range(len(str1))` and change `key` to `str1[i]`.

Comment: Changing key to str1[i] didn't seem to work for me, do you mind showing me what you tried?